# Cannot log in to ssh

Tags: raspbian, ssh, raspberry-pi-os, raspberry-pi-desktop

I was editing my `nano xstartup` file to enable copy and paste over vnc. But after editing it, when I try to log in to my raspberry pi ssh it did not work. Instead, I got the following message:

```
usage: ssh [-46AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-B bind_interface]
           [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec] [-D [bind_address:]port]
           [-E log_file] [-e escape_char] [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11]
           [-i identity_file] [-J [user@]host[:port]] [-L address]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-Q query_option] [-R address] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] destination [command]
```

How should I solve this problem?

Comment: The error message indicates you're not passing the required arguments to `ssh`. How are you calling it?

Comment: Simply using `ssh` doesn't SSH into your Pi - the program doesn't know what to SSH into. The most common usage is `username@IP.Address`. Are you just using `ssh`?